# How to find the odds of (see question)

Tags: statistics

I'm doing an astrology experiment project.

There are 4 groups of astrology types. The 4 groups are Fire, Air, Earth & Water.

Now let's say we have a test group of 100 people and each individual person can possess 2 of the types. Either 2 different types i.e. "fire" and "air" or a twin set i.e "fire" and "fire".

What is the chance that a person will have the element "fire" in 1 of their 2 "slots"?

And statistically how many in the test group of 100 will have "fire" in 1 of their 2 "slots"?

Comment: In at least one of their slots? Or in only one of their slots?

Comment: In at least of one of their slots.

Comment: Are the types (A,B) and (B,A) considered different from each others?

Answer (score 0):

The probability a person does NOT choose fire in both their slots is $(3/4)^2 = 9/16$, so the probability they choose fire for at least one slot is $7/16$. In a hundred people, that is approximately
$$
\frac{7}{16}\cdot 100 = 43.75
$$
so about 44 people.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the slots are interchangeable, meaning the pair (A,B) describes the same as the pair (B,A), and the four traits are uniformly-distributed, there are four slots containing fire: $(F,F), (F,E), (F,W),(F,W')$ (where W is Wind, and W' is water), out of a total of $ 4C2=+4=10$ (considering the pairs of the form $(A,A)$) pairs of traits, for a chance of $4$-in $10$, or  around $40$ in $100$.

Comment: Well, that's up to the OP, and I did not see this clearly-stated.

Comment: O.K, you have a point; I was thinking about different things at the same time. I switched it to a total of $4C2=6$ pairs.

Comment: Sorry if I came off to aggressive.

Comment: Actually, you listed both $(F,E)$ and $(E,F)$ If the pairs are interchangeable (which I assumed, and stated so in my post), then only pairs $(A,B)$ with $A \neq B$ should be listed, plus the pairs where both are equal.

Comment: Altho, of course, under the different assumptions you used, my results do not apply.